# how to use Azure Synapse database templates programmatically

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I can create an Azure data lake database with pre-built tables using [Azure Synapse database templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/database-designer/overview-database-templates) from the Synapse Studio UI, but is there a way to use these templates programmatically? So far from my research I have not found a command, API, or SDK for this. Perhaps I could create the database and tables via the UI, then generate the associated spark sql creation scripts, but don't see a way how to do that either. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do either of the prior?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the data lake storage, tables and data insertion programmatically using Azure SDKs. But these templates have been made available to overcome these series of manual tasks. Using these templates save your time and efforts to create an environment and sample data for your development.

Therefore, asking to deploy these templates programmatically challenging the complete concept of templates. If you want to deploy these resources manually, you can use Azure SDKs.